# Problemas al Generar informes con Itext 5 Java

Tags: java, mysql, itext, apache-netbeans, itextpdf

Estoy generando PDFs en java utilizando la libreria itext5, todo funciona correctamente desde mi computadora, pero si ejecuto el programa desde otra computadora el botón no realiza nada y tampoco sale ningún error, también intente cambiando la ruta, poniendo de ruta la raíz, carpeta de documentos, imágenes y nada (en el otro pc) no genera. Si alguien me puede ayudar, se los agradecería...

Código del botón que genera el pdf:

```
Document documento = new Document();
        
try {
            String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");
            
            PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/Asistencias.pdf"));

            Image logo = Image.getInstance("src/img/logo-preescolar.png");
            logo.scaleToFit(60, 600);
            logo.setAlignment(Chunk.ALIGN_CENTER);

            Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph();
            titulo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            titulo.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 14, Font.BOLD));
            
            titulo.add("Control de asistencia Docentes");

            Paragraph titulo2 = new Paragraph();
            titulo2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            titulo2.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 14, Font.NORMAL));
            titulo2.add("Docentes de primer nivel");

            documento.open();
            documento.add(logo);
            documento.add(titulo);
            documento.add(titulo2);

            PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(6);
            tabla.addCell("  N°  ");
            tabla.addCell("  Fecha  ");
            tabla.addCell("  Nombre  ");
            tabla.addCell("  Hora entrada  ");
            tabla.addCell("  Hora salida  ");
            tabla.addCell("  Obs  ");

            tabla.setWidthPercentage(100); 
            
            try {
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdpreescolar", "root", "");

                PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM asistencia_docentes");

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    do {

                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(1));
                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(2));
                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(3));
                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(4));
                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(5));
                        tabla.addCell(rs.getString(6));

                    } while (rs.next());
                    documento.add(tabla);

                }

            } catch (DocumentException | SQLException e) {
            }
            documento.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El PDF se generó y guardó con éxito\nen el escritorio ✔");
        } catch (DocumentException | HeadlessException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en la imagen " + e);
        }
```

Comment: Primera sugerencia: todos los catch deben tener algo. Como mínimo el `e.printStackTrace();` pa saber qué falló. Segunda sugerencia: revisa los logs de tu aplicación cuando corre en la otra compu y pon la traza relevante aquí en la pregunta. Hay varias opciones de falla comunes en este código (permisos en Desktop, driver no cargado, conexión fallida a la BD) que no sabemos cuál será

Comment: Utilicé e.printStackTrace(); dentro del catch y el error que me generó es este: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Asistencias_Docentes.pdf (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada) Entonces el problema es la manera en la que puse la ruta de guardado, ¿Que ruta entonces debo poner en este pc para que se genere?

Comment: Una que no use _Mis Documentos_ del usuario si el usuario mismo no interviene. No sabemos cómo estás ejecutando esto, así que no sabemos con qué usuario del OS estás generando el reporte y si el proceso tiene permisos para modificar la carpeta (Windows es bien quisquilloso con eso dependiendo de la configuración)

Comment: [SOLUCIÓN] Después de tanto buscar logre hacerlo, lo hice de la siguiente manera:  String rutaEscritorio = /*System.getProperty("user.home") +*/ File.separator + "Desktop";
PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(rutaEscritorio + File.separator + "Asistencias.pdf"));

Comment: La solución la puedes poner en el campo de abajo que dice Tu respuesta. Te puedes responder a ti mismo y puedes recibir puntos de rep de otros usuarios ;)

Answer (score 0):

Después de tanto buscar logré hacerlo, lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
String rutaEscritorio = File.separator + "Desktop"; 

PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(rutaEscritorio + File.separator + "Asistencias.pdf"));
```

Comment: ¡No olvides [edit] y explicar cómo funciona el código! Tal vez para vos sea claro, pero para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar, no. Lee [answer].